# 'int' object is not callable error in min function

Tags: list, dictionary

I am trying to find the minimum value in this list. I started with a dictionary that looked like this:

temperature = {

```
    'June': [25,25,26,27,25,25,24,27,28,28,31,32,33],

    'July': [34,34,36,39,39,38,39,37,39,41,41,39,37],

    'August': [37,37,36,37,35,35,34,37,38,34,32,33,31],
```

}

and I went on to convert my values in a list using

val = (list(temperature.values()))

if I then use the min function to find the minimum value I get a <<'int' object is not callable>> message and this has also appeared in many other attempts. Could you explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct to Tamil's one-liner is

```
min(temperature.items(),key=lambda x :min(x[1]))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you out.

If you want the key and value that contain the `min` value, use this below

```
min(temperature.items(),key=lambda x :x[1])
```

which returns

```
('June', [25, 25, 26, 27, 25, 25, 24, 27, 28, 28, 31, 32, 33])
```

**OR** If you need the `min` value out of this list, use the code below

```
min(min(temperature.items(),key=lambda x :x[1])[1])
```

which returns:

```
24
```

To get only the key which can the minum value in the list, then use this below,

```
min(temperature.items(),key=lambda x :x[1])[0]
```

Output:

```
'June'
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried those and I get the same error!

Comment: what is your python version ?

Comment: 3, it works now I don't know what went wrong before! Thank you so much!! If I want to return only the key, what should I do?

Comment: Cool, Use `min(temperature.items(),key=lambda x :x[1])[0]` this will return only the key.

Comment: Also, I am updating the answer for you

Comment: I voted thank you so much!!